# "expected class-name before '{' token" when compiling

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I've looked a lot, tried a bunch of things I found on stackoverflow and other websites but I still can't figure out how to fix this...

Main C++ file : source.cpp

```
#include "sources.h"
#include "fft_windows.h"
...
```

source.h

```
#include "Array2D.h"
...
```

Array2D.h

```
#ifndef ARRAY2D_H_
#define ARRAY2D_H_

#include <cassert>
#include "Features.h"

template <class T> class Array2D{
...
};
#endif
```

Features.h

```
#ifndef FEATURES_H_
#define FEATURES_H_


#include <string>

using namespace std ;


class Features : public Array2D {
...
};
#endif
```

fft_window.h (function declarations that are defined in fft_window.cpp)

```
//#include "Array2D.h"
template <class T>class Array2D;

void random_example(unsigned int i, Array2D <double> &arr);
...
```

I've tried everything I found and for some reason I still get this error in Features.h on the `class Features : public Array2D {` line...

Any idea ?

Comment: Features.h doesnt knows that is a Array2D, you didnt include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `Features.h` needs to include `Array2D.h`, second you get an infinite include recursion with that, and third you need to specify the template parameter when inheriting from `Array2D`:

```
class Features : public Array2D<int> {
//                  example --- ^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortuatelly I can only accept one answer, and I can't even upvote you because I don't have the rep yet..

Comment: @srsbsns: Np, just roam around SO, collect rep and come back when you have enough. :)

Answer (score 3):

`Array2D` is not a class. `Array2D<int>` is, or `Array2D<float>`

Answer (score 1):

`Array2D` is declared in `Array2D.h` file and you are using that `template class` in `Features.h` without `#include"Array2D.h"`. Include that file as said and also remove the inclusion of `Feature.h` to make sure that there is no recursive includes.

Also, `Array2D` should be used with template argument, like `<int>`, `<char>`, `<T>` and so on.